# Doing simple calculations among rows that satisfy specific conditions in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have two pretty large DataFrame that are related as follows. The first DataFrame takes `ID` as indices and specifies `Min` and `Max`. The second DataFrame has a bunch of scores and prices for each `ID`.

For each `ID`, I want to find the average of the prices that correspond to the scores that are between the `max` and `min scores` of that `ID`.

An example:

```
dt = [[1,3],[0,2],[1,3],[0,3],[1,4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns = ['Min score','Max score'],index=[1,2,3,4,5])

dt_2 = [[1,1,10],[1,4,12],[1,3,20],[1,1,3],[2,3,2],[2,1,4],[3,1,7],[3,2,9],[3,2,3],[4,4,4],[4,2,3],[4,1,2],[5,1,1],[5,3,5],[5,5,5],[5,0,10]]

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dt_2,columns = ['ID','score','price'])
```

The output I want is

```
ID  Avg
1   11
2   4
3   6.33
4   2.5
5   3
```

For example, for `ID=1`, `min score=1` and `max score=3`, so only prices 10, 20 and 3 are relevant. The average of these is 11.

Is there a built-in pandas function that deals with this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df_3 = pd.merge(df_2, df, left_on="ID", right_index=True, how="left")
df_3[
    (df_3.score >= df_3.loc[:, "Min score"]) & (df_3.score <= df_3.loc[:, "Max score"])
].groupby("ID").price.mean()
```

Comment: `df_3.loc[:, "Min score"]` is better `df_3["Min score"]`

Comment: ah ok.  Thanks for the tip. Which situations can lead to trouble with `.loc` option?

Comment: No trouble, only simplier ;)

Comment: When I ran both your and Chris's code on my data, your code is almost 20 times faster. Is it because yours uses vectorization and his uses lambda function? (I'm really new to this, so I just want to understand what's going on)

Comment: I am no expert either, but `apply` seems to be the culprit. May be some more knowledgeable fellow can clarify. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `Series.between`:

```
new_df = df_2.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: x["price"][x["score"].between(*df.loc[x.name])].mean())
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
ID
1    11.000000
2     4.000000
3     6.333333
4     2.500000
5     3.000000
dtype: float64
```

Added:

- `x.name`: value of the group key of groupby object, i.e. `ID` in `df_2` which is used as a look up value for `df`
- `df.loc[x.name]`: looking up `Min Score` and `Max Score` value based on the `ID` from `df_2`
- `*df.loc[x.name]`: unpacks two values (min score and max score) into `pandas.Series.between` to fill up `left` and `right` parameters.

Comment: @Chris could you kindly explain what this is doing `*df.loc[x.name]`?

Comment: @DavidErickson I've added some explanation. Let me know if anything is still unclear :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make the dataframes ready for merging by resetting the index and renaming it to the 'ID' column and then merging the two dataframes naming it new_df:

```
new_df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ID'}).merge(df_2,on='ID')
```

Then I would do the following .loc to make sure you have the min_score and max score only:

```
min_max_df = new_df.loc[(new_df['score'] >= new_df['Min score'])&(new_df['score']<=new_df['Max score'])]
```

And then I would use the groupby() pandas method with .mean() to get the average:

```
min_max_df.groupby('ID').mean()
```

Which would lead to the result:

```
        Min score  Max score     score      price
ID                                           
1         1.0        3.0  1.666667  11.000000
2         0.0        2.0  1.000000   4.000000
3         1.0        3.0  1.666667   6.333333
4         0.0        3.0  1.500000   2.500000
5         1.0        4.0  2.000000   3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge on `ID` filter for the appropriate rows with `.loc` and use `.groupby` for the mean.

```
dt = [[1,3],[0,2],[1,3],[0,3],[1,4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns = ['Min score','Max score'],index=[1,2,3,4,5])
df = df.reset_index().rename({'index' : 'ID'}, axis=1)
dt_2 = [[1,1,10],[1,4,12],[1,3,20],[1,1,3],[2,3,2],[2,1,4],[3,1,7],[3,2,9],[3,2,3],[4,4,4],[4,2,3],[4,1,2],[5,1,1],[5,3,5],[5,5,5],[5,0,10]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dt_2,columns = ['ID','score','price'])
df_new = pd.merge(df_2, df, how='left', on='ID')
df_final = df_new.loc[(df_new['Min score'] <= df_new['score']) & (df_new['score'] <= df_new['Max score'])]
df_final = df_final.groupby('ID')['price'].mean().reset_index().rename({'price' : 'Avg'}, axis=1)
df_final
```